# Ruby NetLdap - Move user entry from one container to another in Samba4

Tags: ruby, active-directory, ldap, samba, netldap

I'm using net-ldap's `rename` method to move a user from one OU to another; however, I am getting an "Old RDN must be deleted" error:

```
#<OpenStruct code=53, error_message="00002035: Unwilling to perform. Old RDN must be deleted", matched_dn="", message="Unwilling to perform">
```

Here's the method I created:

```
def self.move(user, group)
  new_rdn = "CN=#{user.cn.first}"
  new_superior = "OU=#{group},OU=People,DC=example,DC=com"
  ldap_connection.rename(
    olddn: user.dn, 
    newrdn: new_rdn, 
    delete_attributes: true, 
    new_superior: new_superior
  )
end
```

The same response occurs when trying to change just the `RDN` (CN) as well.  The server being contacted is a Samba4 server.  Adding, deleting, updating, etc. are all working as expected.  Only having trouble with renaming.

Comment: Thanks for the rename/modify_dn example. This method was never documented in net-ldap for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally discovered the answer.  The problem is the way the gem is encoding the `true` value for `delete_attributes`, so it was never getting the message to delete the old RDN.  I cloned my own copy of the gem and made the following change:

File: `lib/net/ber/core_ext/true_class.rb`

```
def to_ber
   "\x01\x01\xFF".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
end
```

The code for `false` can also be changed (I don't have any place I use "false" myself).

File: `lib/net/ber/core_ext/false_class.rb`

```
def to_ber
  "\x01\x01\x00".force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT")
end
```

This solution can be found in [Issue #31](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/issues/31) for the gem.